# What are some practical applications of measure theory apart from providing theoretically rigourous foundations?

Tags: measure-theory

It seems that measure theory has a very good *theoretical* purpose, in that it provides a rigorous framework to define a lot of what we do in analysis. However, I have a hard time thinking of a situation where you need to invoke a purely measure-theoretic concept that is not serving as a "shoring up" lemma/theorem to the "main idea", which will often be some integral or limit.

Are there instances where the measure theoretic idea is *the* crux of a result that *isn't* related to probability theory? At the broader level, where are non-probabilistic measureable spaces even used?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_measure_theory

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks, that looks like a good example of what I was talking about. Diff. Geo + measure theory > Diff. Geo :)

Comment: What's a non probabilistic measure space? One where the measure isn't real, nonnegative, and bounded?

Comment: @Tim Kinsella yes...any measurable space not satisfying conditions for a probability space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@WillJagy pointed me to Geometric Measure Theory, which *requires* measures to understand areas/lengths of things like fractals.